# Setting the source for Phonon::VideoPlayer

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

Here is the link to [my .ui file](http://www.mediafire.com/?evd5d2dn200a1tr).  And here is the code to start the GUI:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from gui import Ui_Form

class StartQT4(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = StartQT4()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

py 
And here is the GUI Class Code (.py):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'FinalGUI.ui'
#
# Created: Mon Oct  3 21:53:33 2011
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.8.5
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(599, 557)
        Form.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Form", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(Form)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 601, 561))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tabWidget"))
        self.intro = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.intro.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("intro"))
        self.frame = QtGui.QFrame(self.intro)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 561, 511))
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("frame"))
        self.textBrowser = QtGui.QTextBrowser(self.frame)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 541, 361))
        self.textBrowser.setHtml(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:8pt; font-weight:600; text-decoration: underline;\">Revolution of Music</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:11pt; font-weight:600; text-decoration: underline; vertical-align:sub;\">By Casey and Caleb</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt; vertical-align:sub;\">Coded with Python</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt; font-weight:600; vertical-align:sub;\">[INSERT INTRODUCTION PARAGRAH]</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:8pt; vertical-align:sub;\"></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><img src=\":/musicPic/Current-Music.jpg\" /></p></body></html>", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textBrowser"))
        self.checkBox = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.frame)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 430, 81, 17))
        self.checkBox.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Project Idea", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.checkBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox"))
        self.checkBox_2 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.frame)
        self.checkBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 450, 81, 17))
        self.checkBox_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Research", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.checkBox_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_2"))
        self.checkBox_3 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.frame)
        self.checkBox_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 470, 70, 17))
        self.checkBox_3.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Written", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.checkBox_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_3"))
        self.checkBox_4 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.frame)
        self.checkBox_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 490, 70, 17))
        self.checkBox_4.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Done!", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.checkBox_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_4"))
        self.textBrowser_2 = QtGui.QTextBrowser(self.frame)
        self.textBrowser_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 390, 191, 31))
        self.textBrowser_2.setHtml(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:8pt; font-weight:600;\">Project Goals</span></p></body></html>", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.textBrowser_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textBrowser_2"))
        self.line = QtGui.QFrame(self.frame)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 440, 3, 61))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.VLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("line"))
        self.checkBox_5 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.frame)
        self.checkBox_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 430, 81, 17))
        self.checkBox_5.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Learn PyQt", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.checkBox_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_5"))
        self.checkBox_6 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.frame)
        self.checkBox_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 450, 91, 17))
        self.checkBox_6.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Code Program", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.checkBox_6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_6"))
        self.checkBox_7 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.frame)
        self.checkBox_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 470, 70, 17))
        self.checkBox_7.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Compile", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.checkBox_7.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_7"))
        self.checkBox_8 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.frame)
        self.checkBox_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 490, 70, 17))
        self.checkBox_8.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Finished", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.checkBox_8.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_8"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.intro, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.vidTest = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.vidTest.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("vidTest"))
        self.videoPlayer = phonon.Phonon.VideoPlayer(self.vidTest)
        self.videoPlayer.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 571, 431))
        self.videoPlayer.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("videoPlayer"))
        self.seekSlider = phonon.Phonon.SeekSlider(self.vidTest)
        self.seekSlider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 450, 84, 21))
        self.seekSlider.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("seekSlider"))
        self.volumeSlider = phonon.Phonon.VolumeSlider(self.vidTest)
        self.volumeSlider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 450, 109, 22))
        self.volumeSlider.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("volumeSlider"))
        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.vidTest)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 450, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Pause", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
        self.pushButton_3 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.vidTest)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 450, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Stop", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_3"))
        self.radioButton = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.vidTest)
        self.radioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 450, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Play", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.radioButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("radioButton"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.vidTest, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.billHaley = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.billHaley.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("billHaley"))
        self.textBrowser_3 = QtGui.QTextBrowser(self.billHaley)
        self.textBrowser_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 381, 491))
        self.textBrowser_3.setHtml(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:8pt;\"></p></body></html>", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.textBrowser_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textBrowser_3"))
        self.frame_2 = QtGui.QFrame(self.billHaley)
        self.frame_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 30, 191, 491))
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("frame_2"))
        self.graphicsView = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self.frame_2)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 171, 341))
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("graphicsView"))
        self.pushButton_4 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 410, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Source", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_4"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.billHaley, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.tab_4 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab_4"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_4, _fromUtf8(""))

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(2)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton_2, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.videoPlayer.pause)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton_3, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.videoPlayer.stop)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.radioButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("toggled(bool)")), self.videoPlayer.play)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.intro), QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Introduction", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.vidTest), QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Video Test", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.billHaley), QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Bill Haley", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_4), QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Blank :P ", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

from PyQt4 import phonon
```

My question is, how can I get the video player to load [the url](http://vsyamuzika.narod.ru/tvist/Rock_around_the_clock.mp3) so that when I toggle the radio button, labeled, play, to start the music?
Sorry, but I am a novice, and really need this to be done. Please explain it since I need to implement it on a lot of other tabs later. Also, how is the scaling in PyQt4 Designer?
Just need to know so I can make the right dimensions for a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without getting into TOO much detail about how the Phonon package works, here is a quick snippet:

```
from PyQt4.phonon import Phonon

...

source = Phonon.MediaSource("http://vsyamuzika.narod.ru/tvist/Rock_around_the_clock.mp3")
self.ui.videoPlayer.mediaObject().setCurrentSource(source)
self.ui.videoPlayer.play()
```

You can just create a list of MediaSource objects, and swap them into the player.

Comment: I think, that I may love you.

Comment: Ha. Unfortunately they done have a "LOVE" button for users. Only a checkmark for your favorite answer.

Comment: Umm, alright, so I added the code:
http://tinypaste.com/c060fc

And, I am getting it to launch.
I haven't changed anything else. But when I go to my Video Test :P
Tab and click on the Radio button labeled play is does nothing. Is it just that the video URL I put is wrong, or what

Comment: Is that code just a sample? Because its set up to try and play right when the dialog inits and is not wired to any widgets. You would need to connect a signal from the radio to the play() slot on phonon. Assuming this is just a sample, i also dont know if you can play youtube links like that. It might be returning a player thats streams itself. You might only be able to reference urls that return a valid media mime type. See this: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/5203

Comment: I get what you mean now, so I have changed my code to this..
http://tinypaste.com/130e1

I am still a noob to this, so could you just write the line of code to connect the radio button labeled "Play" to that function? I can write the other code for pause, and stop from there. Thanks for staying along and helping.

Comment: bar.addAction(QtGui.QAction('Play', self, triggered=media.play))

I think it'll be similiar to this.

Comment: @user976299 : that would add a menu items to some menu, and would work, but I have updated an example of how to use signal/slot connections: http://tinypaste.com/a5655   
its not the only way to do it. you might even be able to put the MediaSource objects into a list ahead of time so you only build them once, if the media urls are always the same. And then just load the objects in. But you can see an example of using the functools.partial function for throwing together a callback

Comment: @user976299: sorry had an indentation error when I pasted it across..here is a fixed one: http://tinypaste.com/807b9e

Comment: You also MIGHT need to make this correction. I havent tested: `def play_file(self, path="", *args)` because by default, the clicked() signal will send a boolean indicating whether the widget was CHECKED or not. So it will try and tack that onto the end of the function and you can just capture it like that.

Comment: @user976299 - Did you un-accept my answer? I think I have more than explained how to accomplish your goal.